# Macro finding a forgotten \command

Tags: math-mode, macros

I do not know if this question has more to do with the editor I use (which is LaTeXShop, on Mac) or some clever LaTeX package, but I am typesetting some notes for a course and I would like to systematically use a command, say

```
\variable
```

for the variable of functions so that I can write

```
$f(\variable)$
```

and get `$f(x)$` or `$f(Y)$` consistently in the whole document by simply choosing once and for all in the preamble the value of `\variable`. The reason is that in a first version `$f(x)$` might be good, but I think I will eventually want to move to different variable names. The problem is that I have been typing `$f(x)$` automatically for ages now, and I fear that here and there I will write `$f(x)$` instead of `$f(\variable)$` getting the same visual effect if `\variable` is set to `$x$`, so that I will never catch the error while proof reading, but creating a mess the day I will rename my `\variable`. So comes my question: is there a systematic way to ask LaTeX to warn me whenever I use `$x$` "although I wanted to use `\variable`"? Of course, I do not want it to warn me each time I use the letter `x`. (I will be writing in French, and there are a lot of `x`'s here and there in text) nor to warn me about `$f(x)$` and forget about `$g(x)$`.)

Comment: You can write `\newcommand*{\variable}{x}` and later change it to `\newcommand*{\variable}{Y}`. There are ways to warn about an `x` in math-mode by making it active but is this really something you want? Why don’t you search once for `x`s in math-mode and get rid of them? See [A lightweight editor that supports search and replace in math mode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91160)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make `x` math active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%%% The following four lines will make all
%%% explicit `x' in math mode being printed red
\edef\variable{\mathchar\the\mathcode`\x\relax} % this indirectly defines \variable to print an x
\begingroup\lccode`~=`x
\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{{\textcolor{red}{\variable}}}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`x=\string"8000 }

%%% When you're through, remove the lines
%%% above and use the following one
%\newcommand{\variable}{x}


\begin{document}

This is good: $f(\variable)$

This is bad: $f(x)\ne g(x)$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It would be very kind if you could also explain what is going on: in particular, I do not understand where in your code you told LaTeX that $\variable$ corresponds to x, because it is commented in the version I see.

Comment: I tried your code and it is working, although it gives me a bizarre error when I write $x$ as subscript (which is not a big issue, since the point was precisely to remove all these $x$; but can still be annoying if, for any reason, I want to use the $x$-symbol elsewhere...). Any clue?

Comment: @FilippoAlbertoEdoardo With the code I presented, `$a_x$` will indeed give an error, which is not raised when the “more correct” syntax `$a_{x}$` is used. I'll change the code to allow using `$a_x$`.

Comment: thanks! But I can also adapt to $a_{x}$, indeed...